# Не проходит проверка

Tags: php, циклы

Возникла проблема в коде цикла, почему-то не проходит проверка. Причём, пишу or, выводяться все карточки, а пишу and не выводиться ничего, как будто одна карточка тянет за собой все.

```
             <?php while ($card = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
                echo $grcoins[$card['max-rank']] . " " . $grcoins[$logged_user->take_group_info('txtid')];
                if ($grcoins[$logged_user->take_group_info('txtid')] > $grcoins[$card['min-rank']] and $grcoins[$logged_user->take_group_info('txtid')] < $grcoins[$card['max-rank']]) { ?>
                  <div class="ui card">
                     ...
                  </div>
              <?php } } ?>
```

[image: Страничка с AND]

Comment: `and` и `or` вместо `&&` и `||` ?

Answer (score 4):

Надо явно обозначить порядок сравнения скобками или использовать `&&` и `||` вместо `and` или `or`. Операторы `and` или `or` имеют низший приоритет

```
($grcoins[$logged_user->take_group_info('txtid')] > $grcoins[$card['min-rank']]) 
and 
($grcoins[$logged_user->take_group_info('txtid')] < $grcoins[$card['max-rank']])
```

[Логические операторы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Вы правы насчёт замены всех операторов. Кстати прикреплённый вами код так-же не работает.